# sqlite3 update went wrong

Tags: database, sqlite

It's my first time to ask question here, a little nervous...
I met a bug yesterday, I used `sqlite3_exec()` in my `iOS` project, but it went wrong.
I executed update operation, and called back `SQLITE_DONE`，`errormsg` is also null, but the column I updated has changed to be 0!

For example:

```
sprintf(statement, "update table set name = '%s' where id = '%s'", "Micheal Jackson", "1")
```

When operation finished done, I opened the database file and found the name was 0 where the id is 1.It's strange!
Is there anyone else has met this issue?

Comment: It might help if you display some of the contents of the table before the update statement.

Comment: Display table contents? To where?

Comment: Please do not use `sprintf` or other string manipulation functions to pass parameters to your query. It leaves you open to errors and injection attacks. Use query parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *please* use query parameters (`sqlite3_bind` functions) instead of `sprintf` and other string manipulation operations to pass data into a SQL query. Your query will break if `name` has a single quote in it, and a malicious user could use this to break into your database.

As for your question, consider the following example:

```
sqlite> SELECT 1 = '1';
0
```

The string `'1'` is not equal to the number `1`. You wrap the id in single-quotes, which makes it a string, which doesn't equal any number in the id column so nothing is updated.

The correct way to execute this query is this:

```c
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
int err = sqlite3_prepare(db, "update table set name = ? where id = ?", 0, NULL, NULL);
if(err != SQLITE_OK)
    abort(); // or some other error handling

sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "Micheal Jackson", 0, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, 1);

err = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if(err != SQLITE_DONE)
    abort();
```